# How to find out which Bluetooth profile is used for communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, profile

I need to use Bluetooth for communication with another application which sends data via bluetooth SPP profile. I use the Bluetooth Chat app from Android developer site. I am using real phone (HTC Desire) as there is no Bluetooth API in Android emulator. I use a BlueSoleil bluetooth dongle.

When the other application tries to connect to my phone via Bluetooth and send data via SPP, it is not possible to connect the phone to the application. So I tried Windows Hyperterminal to send data and connect the phone through the dongle. In this situation, I can receive the data and display on the phone.

I would like to know how to find out which bluetooth profile was used when communicating with Hyperterminal.

I have read that bluetooth stack has a buggy implementation in HTC Desire and the SPP profile doesn't work consistently always.

Appreciate any suggestion and time spent on this.

Cheers,

Madhu Nandan

Comment: What do you mean by "other application" not able to connect to phone ? which is this application ? can you re-phrase your question and clarify

Comment: The "other application" is a Rhapsody (UML modeling tool) application which sends data on SPP. My Android app is supposed to receive data from that. Hope this clears something.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your Hyperterminal communication - SPP profile that was most likely used.

SPP profile is a generic profile that just establishes the RFCOMM data channel and sets up a virual COM port for applications to open and connect to and send data.
SPP does not specify any data formats or application level communication protocol to be used by application.
So applications at both end should establish the required format/protocol for communication.
Applications sets it selfs up on a virtual COM (over SPP) and advertises itself (on SDP) via a unique UUID (And Service Names)

So I would suggest that you use the chat application as a starting point, and start with connection / reading data etc, then modify it and complete the application that talks to your application on the device. 
(The chat example is meant to work with a remote chat of the same type and is not a generic usage for SPP profile application)
Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have used the chat app with hyperterminal-HT. I send data from HT in the same format I expect to receive from the Rhapsody app. I can read, display and use the data for further action with the Android app. When I try to receive the data in the same format from the Rhapsody app (this app sends data via SPP), it doesn't work. Do you mean to say the bluetooth chat app is not capable of communicating with Rhapsody app over SPP? If so, I would like to know the reason as the phone, HTC Desire, claims to have SPP profile. Or do you say chat app has some limitations?